# Upgrading Hibernate library in JBOSS 6

Tags: hibernate, jboss6.x

Iam developing a java EE 6 application with JBOSS As 6. In JBoss As 6 Hibernate version is 3.6.0 . How can I replace it with 3.6.3 ???

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to find the the current hibernate jars under common/lib.

Make a backup of the directory first, then remove the hibernate jars from them, and replace them with the more current version.